# Native Base: how to find source code of <Input>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I'm using the `<Input>` component from `Native Base` in my React Native app.

I want to find the source code, so I looked in `node_modules/native-base/src/index.js` and it has a line that says `import { Input } from './basic/Input';`. So I went to `node_modules/native-base/src/basic/Input.js`. I tried editing this file in order to see whether it affected the `Input` I had have rendered in my app, and thus confirm whether this is the correct source file. Nothing changed anything; even when I commented out the entire `Input.js` file, nothing changed.

Where did I go wrong here, and how should I approach finding this file?

Comment: you are using native base package right ?

Comment: @Vijay Yes, I import it with `import {Input} from 'native-base'`

Comment: What is the exact Problem are you facing now in Input Component ?

Comment: render() {
    const { input, meta, ...inputProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <InputGroup underline>
        <Input
          onChangeText={input.onChange}
          onBlur={input.onBlur}
          onFocus={input.onFocus}
          value={input.value}
          {...inputProps}
        />
      </InputGroup>
    );
  }

this is the code Snippets

Comment: Re "What is the exact problem": The text in the Input is not centered vertically. The reason I want to look into the source code is to figure out how the property is controlled, and use that to figure out which props to pass to the <Input> in order to fix the alignment problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 *render() {
        const { input, meta, ...inputProps } = this.props;
    
        return (
          <InputGroup underline>
            <Input
              onChangeText={input.onChange}
              onBlur={input.onBlur}
              onFocus={input.onFocus}
              value={input.value}
              {...inputProps}
            />
          </InputGroup>
        );
      }*
```

Comment: Which code is this you're showing me? Where's it from?

Comment: https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/classes/native-base/Input

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to check the source code, then [checkout](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/components/primitives/Input/Input.tsx)

If you want to update the files in your `node_modules`, you need to know a few things

1. Usually `node_modules/native-base/src` should be the last place you should visit. Because bundlers usually don't look into this.
2. So the code which is actually being used, exist in either of the 2 place based on your bundler.
   `node_modules/native-base/lib/module/components/primitives/Input/Input.tsx`
   `node_modules/native-base/lib/commonjs/components/primitives/Input/Input.tsx`

*NOTE: My answer is based on the assumption you're NativeBase version `3.x`. For `2.x` file path may change a little.*